# What's the name of the genre of algorithms for efficiently collecting common factors?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, reductions, sparse-matrices

I'm working with sparse vectors represented as `index` (array of unsigned integers) and `coefficient` (array of floats with the same dimension).

Suppose I have many vectors of different length, and I want to add them all, summing the corresponding coefficients for each unique index.

I need to calculate it the fastest possible way, since the vector addition may be potentially called millions of times by unknown code using the library.

My starting point is an unique 1D array `index_union` containing all the vectors to be added, with indexes duplicated many times, and a parallel array of the same size, `coefficient_union` holding the coefficients.

The worst problem is finding an unique place in memory, for each index, to accumulate the coefficient sums for that index, and in the end reconstruct the sparse array.

I've considered several approaches:

1. Sorting `index_union` and iterating to find duplicates: This might be slow due to the large number of comparisons, and would require different sorting algorithms for each size.
2. Building a balanced binary tree with `index_union` as keys and accumulating coefficients at each node.
3. Hashing `index_union` and accumulating coefficients in the hash table: This might be fast for lookups, but collisions could be problematic.

I suspect there are existing algorithms specifically designed for this type of operation. However, I'm struggling to find them due to ignorance of the relevant keywords.

Therefore, my question is: What are the names of efficient algorithms for combining sparse vectors with duplicate indices/collecting common factors?

Comment: @Inuyasha Yagami By sparse vector, I mean that I only represent the nonzero elements. `index12` is a product, which produces many repeated indexes, that need to be collected/reduced, so the result has unique indexes. I'm not working with polynomials, but is analogous: if you multiply polynomials, you get the same variables repeated multiple times, and is necessary to collect the coefficients to reduce the polynomial to the minimum expression, like `(x+y)²=x.x+x.y+y.x+y.y=x²+2xy+y²`

Comment: By dimension n, I mean n nonzero coefficients.

Comment: I see. It seems like your problem can be reduced to polynomial multiplication. Is that right? For that, there is a standard $FFT$ algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean by the "product" of two vectors?  Can you define what you are referring to?  Why does the product have dimension $mn$?  Why would indices occur multiple times?  I think I am failing to understand something fundamental.

Comment: @Inuyasha Yagami. No. I'm not doing polynomial multiplication. I only shown polynomial multiplication as example of collecting coefficients.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus I'm asking about the name of algorithms for collecting coefficients, which not necessarily are linked to a product. I guess it should be named something like "array reduction", or "collection of common factors", but searching for that leads nowhere.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to define the problem more clearly.  Please don't put clarifications in the comments -- instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and has all information needed to understand what you are asking.  Our hope is to build a library of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future, and so it helps if the question is explained so that everyone who reads it can understand.

Comment: @D.W I edited it to make it simpler.

Comment: Just use a hash table. This is the standard solution for your problem, and is efficient both in time and space.